# Excel counting line items and not the count from the requested macro

Tags: excel, cells, vba

Using a simple macro:

```
Function CountItalics(r As Range) As Long
    Dim rI As Range
    For Each rI In r
        CountItalics = CountItalics - rI.Font.Italic
    Next rI
End Function
```

This does count the number of Italics but not just the information that is in italic for that cell range, meaning: 
[3 cells not merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdtuf.png)
This will count as 1

But this:
 [3 cells merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiPJR.png)
Will count as 3 (I merged 3 cells to make one).

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Function CountItalics(r As Range)
Dim rI As Range
For Each rI In r
        If rI.Font.Italic Then CountItalics = CountItalics + 1 / rI.Cells.MergeArea.Count
Next rI
End Function
```